# animation not working for the first element of android gallery

Tags: android, android-animation

I have used a gallery. Each item of the gallery takes the full width of the screen. I have also placed a button to flip. When the first item is shown in the gallery if I click the flip button it don't show the animation of flip. But, if I scroll the gallery and go to another item or come back again to the first item then animation works correctly. Can anyone guess where's the problem.

I call the method flipView with selected item's position. The methods and classes for the animations are given below:

```
public void flipView(int position) {
    applyRotation(0, 90, position);
    isFrontShowing[position] = !isFrontShowing[position];       
}

private void applyRotation(float start, float end, int position) {
    // Find the center of image
    final float centerX, centerY;
    if(isFrontShowing[position] == true) {
        centerX = detailsLayout[position].getMeasuredWidth() / 2.0f;
        centerY = detailsLayout[position].getMeasuredHeight() / 2.0f;
        detailsLayout[position].requestFocus();
        detailsLayout[position].bringToFront();
    } else {
        centerX = scriptLayout[position].getMeasuredWidth() / 2.0f;
        centerY = scriptLayout[position].getMeasuredHeight() / 2.0f;
        scriptLayout[position].requestFocus();
        scriptLayout[position].bringToFront();
    }


    final Rotate3dAnimation rotation =
        new Rotate3dAnimation(start, end, centerX, centerY, 200.0f, true);
    rotation.setDuration(350);
    rotation.setFillAfter(true);
    rotation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    rotation.setAnimationListener(new DisplayNextView(isFrontShowing[position], detailsLayout[position], scriptLayout[position]));

    if (isFrontShowing[position] == true)
    {
        detailsLayout[position].startAnimation(rotation);
    } else {
        //System.out.println("---Backward flipping started...");

        scriptLayout[position].startAnimation(rotation);
    }

}



import android.view.animation.Animation;
```

import android.view.animation.Transformation;
import android.graphics.Camera;
import android.graphics.Matrix;

public class Rotate3dAnimation extends Animation {
    private final float mFromDegrees;
    private final float mToDegrees;
    private final float mCenterX;
    private final float mCenterY;
    private final float mDepthZ;
    private final boolean mReverse;
    private Camera mCamera;
    public Rotate3dAnimation(float fromDegrees, float toDegrees,
            float centerX, float centerY, float depthZ, boolean reverse) {
        mFromDegrees = fromDegrees;
        mToDegrees = toDegrees;
        mCenterX = centerX;
        mCenterY = centerY;
        mDepthZ = depthZ;
        mReverse = reverse;
    }

```
@Override
public void initialize(int width, int height, int parentWidth, int parentHeight) {
    super.initialize(width, height, parentWidth, parentHeight);
    mCamera = new Camera();
}

@Override
protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
    final float fromDegrees = mFromDegrees;
    float degrees = fromDegrees + ((mToDegrees - fromDegrees) * interpolatedTime);

    final float centerX = mCenterX;
    final float centerY = mCenterY;
    final Camera camera = mCamera;

    final Matrix matrix = t.getMatrix();

    camera.save();
    if (mReverse) {
        camera.translate(0.0f, 0.0f, mDepthZ * interpolatedTime);
    } else {
        camera.translate(0.0f, 0.0f, mDepthZ * (1.0f - interpolatedTime));
    }
    camera.rotateY(degrees);
    camera.getMatrix(matrix);
    camera.restore();

    matrix.preTranslate(-centerX, -centerY);
    matrix.postTranslate(centerX, centerY);
}
```

}

```
package com.vocabAhead.SATVocab;
```

import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public final class DisplayNextView implements Animation.AnimationListener {
    private boolean mCurrentView;
    RelativeLayout layout1;
    RelativeLayout layout2;

```
public DisplayNextView(boolean currentView, RelativeLayout layout1,
        RelativeLayout layout2) {
    mCurrentView = currentView;
    this.layout1 = layout1;
    this.layout2 = layout2;
}

public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

}

public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
    if(mCurrentView == true)
        layout1.post(new SwapViews(mCurrentView, layout1, layout2));        
    else
        layout2.post(new SwapViews(mCurrentView, layout1, layout2));
}

public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
}
```

}

```
package com.vocabAhead.SATVocab;
```

import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.LinearInterpolator;
import android.view.animation.Animation.AnimationListener;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public final class SwapViews implements Runnable {
    private boolean mIsFirstView;
    RelativeLayout layout1;
    RelativeLayout layout2;

```
public SwapViews(boolean isFirstView, RelativeLayout layout1, RelativeLayout layout2) {
    mIsFirstView = isFirstView;
    this.layout1 = layout1;
    this.layout2 = layout2;
}

public void run() {
    final float centerX, centerY;
    if(mIsFirstView) {
        centerX = layout1.getWidth() / 2.0f;
        centerY = layout1.getHeight() / 2.0f;
    } else {
        centerX = layout2.getWidth() / 2.0f;
        centerY = layout2.getHeight() / 2.0f;
    }

    Rotate3dAnimation rotation;

    if (mIsFirstView == true) {
        layout1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        layout2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        layout2.requestFocus();
        layout2.bringToFront();
        rotation = new Rotate3dAnimation( -90, 0, centerX, centerY, 200.0f, false);
    } else {
        layout2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        layout1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        layout1.requestFocus();
        layout1.bringToFront();
        rotation = new Rotate3dAnimation(-90, 0, centerX, centerY, 200.0f, false);
        //rotation = new Flip3dAnimation(-90, 0, centerX, centerY);
    }

    rotation.setDuration(350);
    rotation.setFillAfter(true);
    rotation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    rotation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {

        }

        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
            WordDetailItemAdapter.notifyAdapter();
        }
    });
    if (mIsFirstView == true) {
        layout2.startAnimation(rotation);
    } else {
        layout1.startAnimation(rotation);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After number of trial and errors I have found a solution of my problem.

In onCreate method in the end I have put the following codes:

```
Handler tempHandler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

            wordDetailAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        };
    };
    Message msg = tempHandler.obtainMessage();
    tempHandler.sendMessageDelayed(msg, 500);
```

The problem was when first time the gallery is shown on the screen the flip animation wasn't working. But, if I scroll the gallery to go other item. After that for every item the animation was working.

The solution worked, but I don't know why the problem was occurring. One thing, the problem wasn't occurring in version 2.1, it was occurring in 2.2 and later.